# Saving Access Token in Auth::gaurd()

Tags: laravel, laravel-passport

I am saving access token in auth guard in laravel 7.0.

```
$token = Auth::guard('admin')->user()->createToken('wallpaper')->accessToken;
Auth::guard('admin')->user()->withAccessToken($token);
dd(Auth::guard('admin')->user());

    #accessToken: 
   "eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiJ9.eyJhdWQiOiIxIiwianRpIjoiYTZiMmJiNjc4MDVhMWRiYTk4ZWFjOTRhOGY0YjRm
    YmNiMTQyYWEzOTc1MDBjYTdjOWI2NTU4MTYzZDU1NmVlMDc3NmQ5NmYyZmM ▶"
```

it saved here but when I access it on the home page it is getting null.

```
dd(Auth::guard('admin')->user());

#accessToken: null
```

how can I access token on that page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you make php artisan make:auth or php artisan ui:auth, this command creates table whit this name: oauth_acces_tokens, here is your token, user_id and more...

Comment: You have service for logout?

Comment: You send this token, to home page? how is your routes? i need more code

Comment: that's not my problem. I am creating an API that has been called from another website. I am securing that API using passport tokens

Comment: if you have any idea how to pass a token from another website and check it here

Comment: Now I make API on my job, on my API one app from flutter send my this token, but you dont need save, is only for check this user exist and is login or not